# Defining lists in VCL (Varnish Configuration Language)

Tags: list, variables, acl, varnish, varnish-vcl

Is there a way to define lists of domains in Varnish VCL language? I suppose something similar for ACLs. I would like to do something like this (using ACLs as an example).

```
acl website_list {
    '(www\.)?domain.tld';
    '(www\.)?domain2.tld';
}
...
if(req.http.Host ~ website_list) return(lookup);
```

I could just use separate RegEx tests but it isn't very re-usable if I want to use those domains somewhere else in the VCL.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you need the lists for?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a test condition which sets a marker header, then test for that later on:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.http.Host ~ "^(www\.)?domain.tld" || 
      req.http.Host ~ "^(www\.)?domain2.tld") {

    /* Set the magic marker */
    set beresp.http.magicmarker = "1";
  }

  if (resp.http.magicmarker) {
    return(lookup);
  }
}
```

Comment: While this solves the specific example given, it's not an answer to the question "How can I define a list in VCL" – I, too, need a way to define a list to be matched against, and this solution doesn't solve my problem :T